# Is there a feature in inteliJ to automatically add a space after '/*' in block comments?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there a feature in inteliJ to automatically add a space after '/*' in block comments?

I think having spaces improves readiability, so I'm considering making a change to include them.

The expected result would be something like `/* abcd */`

Comment: Do you want it as you're typing or just on reformat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code style settings for generated block comments can be found here:

[image]

If you enable the highlighted option and then press `Ctrl+Shift+/` in the editor to insert a block comment stub, it will include spaces between its opening/closing elements and the content, like this: `/* <cursor> */`

I don't believe you can reformat already existing block comments, but you can [multi-select](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/multicursor.html) them in the editor and then press `Ctrl+Shift+/` twice to re-generate the blocks:

[image]

The action can be also found in the main menu under **Code -> Comment with Block Comment**